# Click Once Installer and Anti-Virus Detection

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

We're currently building an Outlook Add In that we package with a Click Once Installer and host on S3 with Cloud Front on top. In it's current state both the manifests and the bootstrapper (setup.exe) have been signed with an authenticode cert from Globalsign. Despite this, several customers have reported that the setup application has been flagged as a virus by Norton (among other products). My question, are there best practices regarding code signing and distribution of Click Once packages that will help mitigate this risk? I've contacted Symantec and so far the only solution they can give me is submitting a whitelist request for every version update we do to the product. Obviously not ideal as it requires users to have the latest whitelists and slows down our delivery of new functionality significantly.

I've also noticed cases where .dll files get flagged as suspicious. I'm looking into signing the assembly files now.
Any help, experience, or anecdotes related to this situation would be supremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, we are currently facing this issue, did you find a solution? We are about to buy a certificate to sign our setup.exe but what I read from your question, this will not solve our issues? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The digital signature doesn't protect anybody/anything from viruses. It is used to confirm that the package comes from a trusted vendor (i.e. confirms your identity). But viruses and other malware is another subject. I'd suggest working with Symantec to produce more suitable solution or try to use any other antivirus software. They can also detect viruses as well (if any).